# fullcalendar add tooltip by hover on day

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm trying to add tooltip here. I'm using the event datesRender

```
   var fcContent = element.query('.fc-day.fc-widget-content');
                            fcContent.forEach(function(content) {
                                content.setAttribute("data-qtip", "Tooltip content");
                            });
```

But after clicking on some day the tooltip does not show again. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: Can we have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please? I assume you're using fullCalendar 4, so I tagged it, but correct me if I'm wrong. And also, what type of object is `element`? Where did it come from? Standard DOM objects in JS don't have a `query` function. It would be good to have enough understanding so we can run some code and reproduce your issue - it will be much easier to diagnose the issue that way.

Comment: I started to make a demo but clearly it doesn't work because `element` is not defined (and as I mentioned above, I don't know how to define it). See here: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEBReVQ . Perhaps you can enhance this demo for us so that we can actually run your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution works with your requirement, but I think the best way could be using a background event. That will work like an annotation but it will not be a tooltip just like a label in the background. Check the documentation below. You can add the title property of the event to show a label in the background.

[Background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events)